# Loading batch of images - Thread allocation

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, operating-system

So, I have a lot of images to be loaded from the disk, I was wondering how many threads should I allocate to the task to obtain maximum performance.

I am not specifying SO because my project is cross-platform.

I think I will work mainly with PNG, i.e. it is not slow to decompress but there is some decompression involved.

Also, if I end up creating one thread for each image, is the thread-overhead big enough to slow down considerably my process?

Comment: Why types of images are you loading?  Is there a lot of CPU time involved in decoding?  If not, then your main bottleneck will be I/O, not CPU and threads might not help that much.

Comment: I will be loading mainly PNG, sir.

Comment: This seems like an obvious candidate for a pipeline approach. One thread sucking things off the disk and then feeding them to the other thread which decodes the image. Multiple threads reading the same disk will just slow you down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sometimes a producer consumer architecture is good enough.
- Other times what you describe could also work, given that you don't have more threads that the CPUs available can handle (ie more threads than #CPUs*2 **usually** (not always) leads to thrashing).

You need to perform some tests in order to see which model works best for you. Think about where do these images come from (disk? Are they in consecutive locations on disk or not. Does it make sense to produce multiple threads and just wait for disk IO to load a small chunk of one photo from disk, then context switch to another thread and do another seek on disk to get a small chunk of another file and so on.

I suggest **try single thread application**.

Comment: Assuming use of synchronous I/O, two threads *might* actually give better performance even if loading two files on the same disk because one thread can be decoding while the other is reading.  This does not generalize, however, to `N` files (in the 1-file-per-thread sense).

Comment: @AndréCaron fully agree. Its what I would do, but then again Andre might not do so much processing other than displaying the image in some container; Also if you have photos stored in a disk array like RAID you can get even better concurrency

Answer (score 2):

One thread per disk seems like a reasonable start.  You could make it a runtime tuning parameter to see what works best, especially if there are, or might be, non-local network disks, (ie. high latency), or, as others have suggested, there is any decompression or video processing to be done.

One thread per image is not a good idea, again, as posted by others.  You will need some P-C queues to feed the thread/s with objects that contain an image buffer + file spec and also to return the same objects after the load is done - continually creating/terminating/destroying threads is wasteful, difficult and prone to disaster.